# prebuilt ffmpeg packages with QSV support for ubuntu

Tags: intel, ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration

Suprisingly i couldn't find any ppa with prebuilt ffmpeg packages to add QSV (intel quicksync video) support.

Are there any, around?
And isn't QSV added by default because it would rely on proprietary code? What other reason could there be, since it's a feature that >50% of the systems have these days?

Comment: You can always compile it.

Comment: of course, always.

Comment: Part of the answer to my question, although hopefully outdated, seems to be at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IntelQuickSyncVideo :
"But there are hidden reasons why we can't use any of this yet in Ubuntu. The problem is that pieces are missing. Both of them have a dependency on a custom proprietary fork of LibVA (VA-API)."


edit: apparently the answer is outdated. as it seems Intel has fixed whatever was blocking this integration

Comment: the link above is heavily outdated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research, got the answer, hopefully useful for sbd else:

Most packages are already available in recent Ubuntus, the only missing one is a properly compiled ffmpeg.
Simple instructions provided by Intel on github:
https://github.com/Intel-Media-SDK/MediaSDK/wiki/Build-and-use-ffmpeg-with-MediaSDK

Note that to enable all codecs, default hardware-accelerated codec packages have to be replaced with non-free versions, as explained here:
https://github.com/Intel-Media-SDK/MediaSDK/wiki/Intel-media-stack-on-Ubuntu

Comment: side note: current ubuntu 20.04 version of libmfx does not seem capable of  encoding hevc main10 profile (reports unsupported profile error) even on hardware supposed to support it (coffee lake)

Comment: Intel requires the purchase of a paid "professional" Media Studio license to enable HEVC (or h265) hardware encoding.  This effectively blocks Ubuntu distributing builds including QSV HEVC support.  It is not clear if the existing libmfx can be "enabled" by giving it a license.

Comment: HEVC default profile works without a license here, are you referring to enabling main10 profile using a license?

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04, instructions are provided by https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/4f831867f8e55d35cbcb527e15f9f116

Notes:
opencl not needed,
working sha1 for libdrm : 52f05d3d